# Как вычислить сумму каждой строки многомерного массива

Tags: java, массивы

> Есть массив:
>
> ```
> int[][] array = new int[2][3];
> array[0][0] = 1;
> array[0][1] = 2;
> array[1][0] = 3;
> array[1][1] = 4;
> array[0][2] = 5;
> array[1][2] = 6;
> ```
>
> Используя цикл for, вычислите сумму каждой строки первого массива и запишите результат в новый массив.

Можете помочь кодом для новичка, т.е простое решение предложить?

Comment: Как вы его заполняете, так и складывайте.

Comment: PS. Если вы научитесь работать с массивом, то с легкостью напишите игру морской бой.  Массив похож на поле морского боя.  [i][j] - это координаты кораблей.

Answer (score 2):

Если легкий вариант и не использую Stream API, то вам подойдет такой вариант:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[2][3];
        array[0][0] = 1;
        array[0][1] = 2;
        array[1][0] = 3;
        array[1][1] = 4;
        array[0][2] = 5;
        array[1][2] = 6;
        int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                newArray[i] += array[i][j];
            }
        }
        Arrays.stream(newArray).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Comment: Программа выводит 8 и 13. Там нужно чтобы суммировались 1+2=3, 3+3 = 7, 5+6 =11. И выводился массив 3, 7, 11. :( Я в печали. Как того достичь?

Comment: У вас массив массивов...и соответственно ваши строки в массиве являются внутренними массивами

Comment: @Anastasia, нынче `3+3` - равно 7 ? странная математика у вас =)

Answer (score 0):

Вот например мы заполняем массив, так же и складывайте элементы массива.
Вот пример заполнения и вывода.

```
    package array;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class ArrayCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[2][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                array[i][j] = i+1;

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(" array[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]" + " = " + array[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

array[i][j] - это ваш элемент массива, то что хранится в ячейке массива с номером ячейки [i][j]. Как в табличке. Только это условно. В памяти компьютера массив хранится по другому. Строки и столбцы - это условность.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
    int rowsCount = array[0].length;
    for(int row = 0; row < rowsCount; row++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            int cell = array[i][row];
            sum += cell;
            // debug (remove next line if not needed!)
            System.out.print(cell + (i < array.length - 1 ? " + " : " = "));
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно проще сделать с помощью `stream`:

```java
int[][] array = new int[2][3];
array[0] = new int[]{1, 2, 5};
array[1] = new int[]{3, 4, 6};

int[] sums = Arrays.stream(array)
        // получаем сумму каждой строки
        .mapToInt(row -> Arrays.stream(row).sum())
        // возвращаем массив
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sums)); // [8, 13]
```